# Sheet name dynamically assigned from a cell value

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

```
Sub CreateWorkSheetByRange()
Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim Ws As Worksheet
 Dim arr As Variant
Dim template As Worksheet
Dim xTitleId As String
On Error Resume Next
xTitleId = "Select Range"
Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
arr = WorkRng.Value
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 arr = WorkRng.Value
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
' Create the Worksheet names based on range selected 
For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
For j = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
Set Ws = Worksheets.Add(after:=Application.ActiveSheet)
  Ws.Name = arr(i, j)
   Next
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly create worksheet names using the values from Excel Cells.
Use the following VBA code

```
Sub CreateWorkSheetByRange()
'variable declaration
Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Dim arr As Variant
Dim template As Worksheet
'**Edit-2:Declared xTitleId**
Dim xTitleId As String
'**Edit-3:Declared i and j**
Dim i as Variant
Dim j as Variant
'Start of Program
On Error Resume Next
'Specify the title of the dialog that requests for range
xTitleId = "Select Range"
' Assign the application.selection function to the variable WorkRng
Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
' Accept input from the user
Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
' Create an array of the input values
arr = WorkRng.Value
' The following line is optional
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
' Create the Worksheet names based on range selected
For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
    For j = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
        Set Ws = Worksheets.Add(after:=Application.ActiveSheet)
        Ws.Name = arr(i, j)
    Next
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The above code allow you to select a range of cells from which you would want to create the names of the worksheets.
You can further build on this and see if you can modify this for your **changing names scenario**
FYI: I'm new to VBA too... but you can learn this very easily

Comment: Thank you for taking time help me, I'm still having troubles I cut and past your cod in new module and tried running it. it stops at xTitleId with message "Compile Error" & "variable not defined" I'm sure this is my lack of knowledge but is there additional steps need to get this to work? Thank you again.

Comment: @Howard - See if it works for you now. I have added the xTitleId declaration part.

Comment: It made it down to For "i" compile error/variable not defined

Comment: @Howard, can you please add your code as a _EDIT_ in your own question - it would be easy to comment on where it could be wrong

Comment: I'm thinking I may be taking on more then I'm ready for.

Comment: Nothing like that. I presume that there is a line on top of all your code called `Option Explicit`. That is why it is demanding to declare all the variables. Anyway - see _Edit:3_ for the added lines in my answer

Comment: That did it very cool.

Comment: Did you say there was way to change it once created?

Comment: Yes. You can customize this piece of code once you are familiar with VBA. Just open the code and press `F8` key and it will step thru the code showing you what it does step-by-step.